# Does Firebase Hosting provide a way to see how many users(access count) visited to the website?

Tags: firebase

Does Firebase Hosting provide a way to see how many users(access count) visited to the website?
If so, where can I view it?
If not, do I have to store access count in database or something?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Google Analytics for this. Visit this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics) for more details about how to use GA with firebase.

Comment: @Daibaku. Hi. I am having the same question as you. I implemented Google Analytics in my web apps and put some events. But how can we read the data? I only see data for the last 30 minutes when I look.

Answer (score 0):

Basic entry to Google Analytics

1. Go to https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/
2. Select your project
3. On the left sidebar, select Build > Hosting
4. Click Usage tab
5. Click View in Cloud Logging
   [image: Firebase > Hosting > Usage > Cloud Logging]
6. It should show you a basic query and histogram of visits (I purposely did not include the logs in the screenshot below)
   [image: Google Analytics query and histogram]

Get more info from here https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics